# Event button behind : AJAX, C#, asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, button

To resume in one line :
I made an AJAX request to build a table with a button, then take this button and display it. The problem is between the event and the postback when I click on the button.

I try to make a button and send it with an AJAX request :
Here's the AJAX part :

```
  $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "WebForm1.aspx/createTable",
            data: JSON.stringify({ id: idArgument }),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function(msg) 
            {
                 if(msg.d != "")
                 {
                        $('#tableauArticles').empty();
                        $('<div class="newtable">').html(msg.d).appendTo('#tableauArticles');
                  }
             }
       });
```

tableauArticles is a table, where I put the name of a document, and a button.
Here's "createTable" :

```
 var page = (WebForm1)HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler;
 System.Web.UI.WebControls.Table tableau = page.CreateTableNonStatique(id);

  var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
  using (var htmlWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter))
  {
         tableau.RenderControl(htmlWriter);
  }
  string tableauString = stringWriter.ToString();

  return tableauString;
```

CreateTableNonStatique is just a function that create a table in the c# code, and it seems to work because I see what I want to see.
The problem is with the button (on the table) :
When I click on it, it will refresh the page.

I've searched, and seen a lot of things that prevent the postback :

```
boutonLire.OnClientClick = "return false;";
```

or

```
boutonLire.UseSubmitBehavior = false;
```

**and it work**, but I have **no event** : it will not postback, but it will do nothing, even with

```
boutonLire.Click += new EventHandler(testReturn);

boutonLire.Click += (sender, eventArgs) =>
{
    // function
}
```

and the worst part,

```
boutonLire.OnClientClick = "test(); return false;";
```

let the button refresh the page, just as

```
boutonLire.OnClientClick = "return testReturn();";

public bool testReturn()
{
    return false;
}
```

Here's my whole near the button, with the tests I made :

```
           TableCell celluleBouton = new TableCell();
           Button boutonLire = new Button();

           boutonLire.Text = "Telecharger";
           boutonLire.ID = svgID.ToString();
           boutonLire.Attributes.Add("OnClick","testReturn(event);"); 

           /*boutonLire.OnClientClick = "return testReturn();";
           boutonLire.UseSubmitBehavior = false;
           boutonLire.Click += new EventHandler(testReturn);

           boutonLire.Click += (sender, eventArgs) =>
           {
                Guid fichierID = svgID;
                if (fichierID == null)
                    fichierID = Guid.Empty;
                buttonDownload_Click(fichierID);
            };*/

            celluleBouton.Controls.Add(boutonLire);
            tableColonne.Cells.Add(celluleBouton);
            tableau.Rows.Add(tableColonne);
```

And the script, under the Neel's help :

```
<script> 
    $(function testReturn(event) 
    {
        alert("beforePrevent"); 
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("afterPrevent");
    }) 
</script>
```

will show me "beforePrevent" at every refresh , and never "afterPrevent".

Thanks !

Comment: If you are using that button only for client side click then why don't you just use `input type="button"` html control instead of asp.net `<asp:button>` control?

Comment: hi can you explain your problem in one line /

Comment: @GuruprasadRao I admit that I just don't know html : it was already a battle to pass a table from C# to AJAX then traduce it to display it... 
I learned to use asp.net function, because of the page that I manually made, but never used htmls controls : will it be easier for the events and my problem ?

Comment: @Neel In one line : I have a problem between postback and event that I want for a button : I succeed to prevent postback, but my button don't do anything now

Comment: yep.. just show me your asp:button line of code!! I'll give equivalent html line!!

Comment: The thing is that I create a button in C#, with asp.net control then I traduce it as a string in Html, then I build it : I think that the problem will bee the same, Html or Asp.net hadle the sames events problems no ?

Answer (score 1):

while clicking this link, `return false` will cancel the `default behavior` of the browser.

It means all the other browser behaviors will be caceled .

**So what to do?**

Well you can use `event.preventDefault()` instead of returning false!

Give it a try!

Check this out :- http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/

Comment: The problem is that I create the button in C# : I don't have something like 

`$("button").click(function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
}`

no ?

Comment: you can creat testReturn() method in js file and in that function you can write event.preventDefault()

Comment: `boutonLire.OnClientClick = "testReturn";` then `<script>$(function testReturn() {  event.preventDefault(); }) </script>`

But it seems inefficient, it refresh all. The button is created in C#, so the event too, and it must call a script from my asp.net page ? It seems strange at my eyes, I thought of just a call of a C# functtion

Comment: you need to pass event along with testReturn like testReturn(event); and in  <script>$(function testReturn(event) { event.preventDefault(); }) </script>

Comment: `boutonLire.OnClientClick = "testReturn(event);";`  then `<script>
            $(function testReturn(event)  {  event.preventDefault(); alert("here");  })</script>` don't display anything =/

Comment: boutonLire.Attributes.Add("OnClick","testReturn(event);"); @Pingu

Comment: Ow ! I didn't know that I can access OnClick by this way :
Now, I'm sure he goes in the function but it's strange : It refresh me everytime I click, but `<script> $(function testReturn(event)  { alert("test"); event.preventDefault();}) </script>`
will show me "test" at every refresh, and `event.preventDefault();alert("test"); `
won't show anything

Comment: Thanks for the interest, I progressed thanks to you : I updated my original post, and I'll keep it update

Answer (score 0):

Here the answer, for me :
return false; is suffisant, but event.preventDefault() must work too (I just didn't know how to pass event as an argument, but... This code work )

```
 TableCell celluleBouton = new TableCell();
 System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button boutonLire = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button();

  boutonLire.Text = "Telecharger";
  boutonLire.ID = svgID.ToString();

  boutonLire.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return clicArticle(this);");

  // on le crée graphiquement
  celluleBouton.Controls.Add(boutonLire);
  tableColonne.Cells.Add(celluleBouton);
  tableau.Rows.Add(tableColonne);
```

So, when it's clicked :

```
 <script>
        function clicArticle(boutton)
        {
            var idArgument=boutton.id;

            $.ajax
            ({
                type: "POST",
                url: "WebForm1.aspx/telechargerStatique",
                data: JSON.stringify({ id: idArgument }),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function(msg) 
                {
                    alert(msg.d);
                    // here, display the file      
                    return false;
                }
            })
            return false;
        }
    </script>
```

I hope it'll help someone ! Thanks !